# Python inserting a short integer into a list of bytes

Tags: python, list

I have a list of bytes as follows

```
pkt_bytes = [ 0x02,0x07, 0xff,0xff ,0x00,0x03]
```

in the position `0xff,0xff` I want to put a 16bit short integer

How do I do it

Regards

Comment: Do you want to *replace* the two items `0xff` with something? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Hi

I think I need to use the struct pack function (I will need to insert other data types into the packet apart from short integers). I am trying to construct packets to send over a network, it is big endian format

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`struct` module](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) to pack values into appropriate formats:

```
>>> pkt_bytes = [0x02, 0x07, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0x03]
>>> myint = 123
>>> pkt_bytes[3:5] = [ord(b) for b in struct.pack("H",myint)]
>>> pkt_bytes
[2, 7, 255, 123, 0, 3]
```

By default this will use the native byte order but you can override this using modifiers to format string.  Since your variable is called `pkt_bytes` I'm guessing you want network (big-endian) byte order which is signified by a `!`:

```
>>> struct.pack("!H",5000)
'\x13\x88'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
>>> pkt_bytes.insert(3, 0xaa)

>>> help(pkt_bytes.insert)
Help on built-in function insert:

insert(...)
    L.insert(index, object) -- insert object before index
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below will replace every occurrence of `0xff` with `0x04` until there are no more `0xff` left in the list.

```
pkt_bytes = [0x02, 0x07, 0xff, 0xff ,0x00, 0x03]
while True:
    try:
        idx = pkt_bytes.index(0xff)
        pkt_bytes[idx] = 0x04
    except ValueError:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> pkt_bytes = [ 0x02,0x07, 0xff,0xff ,0x00,0x03]
>>> pkt_bytes[2:4] = [pkt_bytes[2] << 8 | pkt_bytes[3]]
>>> pkt_bytes
[2, 7, 65535, 0, 3]
```